# @JsonIgnoreProperties not working for swagger generation

Tags: java, swagger, rest, springfox

Am trying to hide few fields of an object for specific API Endpoints.

ex:

```
"student": {
    "name": "value1",
    "age": "value2",
    "dob": "value3",
    "value": "value4"
  }
```

I need these some values to be present and hidden for certain API Endpoints.

API 1: GET : /school/student/personal

```
"student": {
    "name": "value1",
    "age": "value2"
  }
```

API 2: GET : /school/student/all

```
"student": {
    "name": "value1",
    "age": "value2",
    "fatherName": "value3",
    "motherName": "value4",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me you are using different object, you could create DTO(Data Transfer Object) and make your API return DTO.

You need adapter to transform your domine object(ex.Student) to DTO object(StudentDTO or TinyStudentDTO)

EX.

API 1: GET : /school/student/personal should return TinyStudentDTO

```
TinyStudentDTO
-name
-age
```

API 2: GET : /school/student/all should return StudentDTO

Your StudentDTO will extend with TinyStudent

```
StudentDTO 
-fatherName
-motherName
```

Comment: Hey Thanks mate, I found this one.

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2613


its showing as it's fixed.

Comment: showing as fixed but not working still. 